# Faulting Application installutil.exe

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, installation

This is the Random error im getting

```
Faulting application installutil.exe, version 1.0.3705.6018, stamp 40f6266d, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.2756, stamp 44c60f39, debug? 0, fault address 0x00015e02
```

Any ideas any one? why should installuti.exe through a `faulting module kernal32.dll`

Server Version : Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition

Could it be framework issues

Edit:

It seems like a Stackoverflow issue but the thing is its not the code that is throwing the error.

My Installer does three simple tasks

1. Copy the files from the folder to the local directory
2. Create the registry keys in HKEY_LOCALMACHINE/SOFTWARE/MySoftware/
3. Then using installutill.exe to install the service from the local folder
4. and then starting the service

I have tested this process on our local Windows Server 2003 Enterprize Edition and it seems to work. and thats what i cant get my head around. why would it work on one windows server and not on the other one.

One difference that i thought about is because our client is installing in VMware, would that change how windows functions differently in a virtual enviornment rather than a physical.

Comment: anything in the eventlog?

Comment: I wish this server was in my control and i could copy and paste that... but i can at the moment... i will have to request that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you installing or otherwise doing when this happens?

***Edit :***
I'm having a tough time understanding what you're doing. Can you edit your original question to explain, in clear detail, what you're doing and at what point you get the error?

Since it sounds like you're trying to write an installer for your own program, this may be better-placed on StackOverflow, and not on ServerFault.

Doing some Googling does hint that it may be a problem of a framework not installed properly on a client machine, or a resource issue. I think that means it could be just about anything, and maybe you should add some better error-logging to your code.

Comment: Create Registry HKEYLOCALMACHINE/SOFTWARE/OurSoftware/ run installutill.exe to install the service and then start the service. But if there were registry problems we would get exceptions on the install software and not with installutil.exe. However i will try doing this manually on the server tomorrow to see if it works... could it be the registries?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. cause i think you are right. issue maybe with the framework not installed properlly. But im still not sure